# How to display the Command prompt during Logon with a batch file

Tags: command-line

I have a logon script which runs the 'sc config winrm type= own' command.
This command changes the registry value at this location:
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\WinRM

From this
Type = 0x00000020 (32)

To This
Type = *0x00000010 (16)*

How do i get the *changed Registry entry* to display in the command prompt at **logon** for couple of seconds or until user closes the command prompt?

for example:
I want the output to show:

```
ValueName: Type
ValueType: REG_DWORD
ValueValue:0x10
```

Comment: Are you trying to run external programs from the logon screen, is that your question?  There is a way, though not exactly ethical.  If interested, reply.

Comment: Apologies - By logon i meant 'After login, when the desktop loads up'. Not trying to run any external programs.

Answer (score 0):

Run your batch file using classic star-up option from start menu and use the timeout,sleep and/or pause batch commands to display the prompt as you see fit.

example: `timeout /t 2` used at the end of the script will display the content 2 seconds then the prompt will auto-exit.

Comment: I'm not sure if the inquirer was asking about *after login*, or *at login prompt*.

Comment: Commands like timeout work anyway and a cmd can be launched at login prompt using various ways like (ease of access).

Comment: Yes that was the shotty method I was going to post.  Sticky keys works as well.  There is also a way where you duplicate a windows startup program (like explorer.exe), then it runs "its stuff", then starts the real exploerer.exe.  That would run as the user logs in.

Comment: I remember a virus I analyzed once even managed to run one of its .exes as main explorer.exe parameter.

Comment: Yeah a little dll injection can do that.  I'm not actually sure how those things get there, since I've always had to go through my Linux dual boot to change any of those files...?

Comment: @coltonon By logon i meant 'After login, when the desktop loads up'

Comment: Then @Overmind's method works for you.